# Can I reduce this method to instantiate an object and push into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reading a .csv file into an array. The file simply contains employee information (last name, first name, job, etc). I ultimately want to create a matrix where a single-dimensional array is populated with each person object. This is the code I have:

```
function setStaffData() {
    /** @type {Array.<string>} */
    var lines = [],
        person = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data/staff2.csv',
        contentType: "text/csv",
        async: false,
        success: function(text) {
            lines = text.split(/\n/);
        }
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        lines[i] = lines[i].replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
        person[i] = lines[i].split(",");
        staff[i] = new PersonClass(person[i][0], person[i][1], person[i][2], person[i][3], person[i][4], person[i][5], person[i][6], person[i][7]);
    }
}
```

How can I shorten the process by not using the person array?

Comment: dont use `async:false` its a huge anti-pattern. Its not clear what you mean either - what do you want to use *in place of the `person` array*?

Comment: Have you looked at this plugin?  http://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/

Comment: @Jamiec: I am just trying to be more concise and use less memory when I program.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't seem to be using the contents of each entry in `person` beyond the loop iteration in which it's filled, you can just use a single variable instead:

```
function setStaffData() {
    /** @type {Array.<string>} */
    var lines = [],
        person;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data/staff2.csv',
        contentType: "text/csv",
        async: false,
        success: function(text) {
            lines = text.split(/\n/);
        }
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        lines[i] = lines[i].replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
        person = lines[i].split(",");
        staff[i] = new PersonClass(person[0], person[1], person[2], person[3], person[4], person[5], person[6], person[7]);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

It's possible to shorten this even further to eliminate the `lines` array as well:

```
function setStaffData() {
    /** @type {Array.<string>} */
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data/staff2.csv',
        contentType: "text/csv",
        // note: removed "async: false"
        success: function(text) {
            var lineRegex = new RegExp('.*\n', 'g');
            var match, line, person;
            while (match = lineRegex.exec(text)) {
                line = match[0].replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
                person = line.split(",");
                staff.push(new PersonClass(person[0], person[1], person[2], person[3], person[4], person[5], person[6], person[7]));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. As an aside, I haven't been able to get the function to work without the async: false.

Comment: This approach will work even if you use async:false.  I just removed it because the code all fit into the success handler function.